# Usage of YUI Compressor Maven Mojo minifying javascript

Tags: javascript, jsp, maven, package, minify

I work on a struts2 project using maven to compile.  I am trying to minify the javascript files, which are located in different locations.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>net.alchim31.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>yuicompressor-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.0</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <goals>
          <goal>compress</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>        
    <configuration>
      <nosuffix>true</nosuffix>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

I assume that by doing this, all js files will be minified and replaced the original file in the production war file (according to definition for nosuffix).

However it doesn't seem to be the case. How can I acheve this?

Secondly, if I choose to use the one with the suffix, I assume I have to manually change the scripts reference in my jsp files is that correct? If so, how do I set it so that it will remove the original without the suffix?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found working solution [here](https://github.com/xwiki/xwiki-platform/blob/master/xwiki-platform-core/xwiki-platform-web/pom.xml). Basically you need to place the following into you pom.xml (replacing only the path to you js and css files inside src/main/webapp folder):

```
    <build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <webResources>
                    <!-- Add minified resources -->
                    <resource>
                        <directory>${project.build.directory}/minimized</directory>
                        <targetPath>/</targetPath>
                        <filtering>false</filtering>
                    </resource>
                </webResources>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>net.alchim31.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>yuicompressor-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>compress</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <nosuffix>true</nosuffix>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>

    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <!-- Javascript and CSS files compression -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>net.alchim31.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>yuicompressor-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <!-- Don't output in the default webapp location, since the war plugin will overwrite the files in there
                    with the original, uncompressed ones. -->
                    <webappDirectory>${project.build.directory}/minimized</webappDirectory>
                    <jswarn>false</jswarn>
                    <!-- Overwrite existing files -->
                    <nosuffix>true</nosuffix>
                    <includes>
                        <include>%path to your js and css files inside src/main/webapp%/**/*</include>
                    </includes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
    </build>
```

Comment: +1 for link, but the only thing you forgot to include here is : <webappDirectory>${project.build.directory}/minimized</webappDirectory>   in yiucompressor's configuration block

Comment: What you suggest actually cannot work - it will miss all the static resources, templates and web.xml fro src/main/webapp

Comment: Hi, @IvanSopov This plugin will compress all .js and .css files under src/main/webapp. But in my case I have my .js and .css files under src/main/resources/static, so how can I change that default path to this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi, @davs This plugin will compress all .js and .css files under src/main/webapp. But in my case I have my .js and .css files under src/main/resources/static, so how can I change that default path to this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: This case may have solution but the plugin version 1.5.1 has a bug because it cannot be configured for some simple cases. Say we want to configure webappDirectory and sourceDirectory.

If sourceDirectory is configured different from the default then the plugin executes compression twice once with the configured value and then with the default value which defeats the purpose of sourceDirectory configuration.

I haven't been able to compress from a directory that had to have changes made before compression.