# How to exclude a folder from YUI compressor

Tags: javascript, eclipse, maven, minify, yui-compressor

I want to exclude a folder containing a set of javascript files that YUI compressor would not compile and pump out errors. I am trying this with the `<exclude>folder</exclude>` tag, which is not working - YUI is still trying to compress the files in the folder.

Below is my pom configuration:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>net.alchim31.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>yuicompressor-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.1</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>compressyui</id>
                <phase>process-resources</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>compress</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <nosuffix>true</nosuffix>
                    <warSourceDirectory>src/main/webapp</warSourceDirectory>
                    <jswarn>false</jswarn>
                    <sourceDirectory>src/main/webapp/js-max</sourceDirectory>
                    <webappDirectory>src/main/webapp</webappDirectory>
                    <outputDirectory>src/main/webapp/js</outputDirectory>
                    <force>true</force>
                    <excludes>
                          <!-- yuicompressor fails to compile patterns library, hence stopping full build -->
                          <!-- We won't be modifying this library so will exclude it for now -->
                          <exclude>src/main/webapp/js-max/patterns/*</exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Any idea how to accomplish this?

Comment: Take a loot at that post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11836599/usage-of-yui-compressor-maven-mojo-minifying-javascript

Comment: @Tunaki Thanks mate, I have found the solution :)

Comment: Hi, @Tunaki This plugin will compress all .js and .css files under src/main/webapp. But in my case I have my .js and .css files under src/main/resources/static, so how can I change that default path to this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi, @JoelMin This plugin will compress all .js and .css files under src/main/webapp. But in my case I have my .js and .css files under src/main/resources/static, so how can I change that default path to this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Found the solution, and I'm posting here so everyone can see. For my case, the following worked:

Instead of `<exclude>src/main/webapp/js-max/patterns/*</exclude>`, I had to use `<exclude>**/patterns/*</exclude>`. So the following is the complete pom config that worked for me:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>net.alchim31.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>yuicompressor-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.1</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>compressyui</id>
            <phase>process-resources</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>compress</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <nosuffix>true</nosuffix>
                <warSourceDirectory>src/main/webapp</warSourceDirectory>
                <jswarn>false</jswarn>
                <sourceDirectory>src/main/webapp/js-max</sourceDirectory>
                <webappDirectory>src/main/webapp</webappDirectory>
                <outputDirectory>src/main/webapp/js</outputDirectory>
                <force>true</force>
                <excludes>
                      <!-- yuicompressor fails to compile patterns library, hence stopping full build -->
                      <!-- We won't be modifying this library so will exclude it for now -->
                      <exclude>**/patterns/*</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </configuration>
    </execution>
</executions>
```

Comment: Hi, @JoelMin <warSourceDirectory> is where your js, css files are, right? And if I change this path to 'src/main/resources/static' will that work as well. Actually I have my jss and css file in the above-mentioned folder. Thanks in advance.